# PHP contact form sends empty data

Tags: php, forms, html

I am trying to create a HTML5 contact form compatible with computer and mobile devices, when I clicked on send message it jumps into a blank white screen. I do get a email but it contains no information. I am quite new with PHP.

For www.rare1.ca/test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive HTML5/CSS3 template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1, minimum-    scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagewidth">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="center">
            <nav id="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#pagewidth"><span>gallery</span></a></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactUs"><span>contact us</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="center">
              <h1><img src="img/logo.gif" width="142" height="78"></h1>
                <strong class="subHeading">Coming soon</strong>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li><img src="img/img-gallery.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                        <li><img src="img/img-gallery2.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                        <li><img src="img/img-gallery3.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
                <div class="buttons"></div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contactUs" class="row grey">
            <div class="center">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <strong class="subHeading">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="half">
                        <form action="sendemail.php" class="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <h2>Feedback form</h2>
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="textField"><input type="text" name="Name" id="name" placeholder="Your name ..." /></div>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="textField"><input type="text" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email ..." /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="textField"><textarea name="Message" cols="20" rows="4" placeholder="Your message ..."></textarea> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <button class="btnSmall btn submit right">
                                                <span>Send Message</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="half">
                        <h2>How to find us</h2>
                        <div id="map">
                            <div class="imgHolder"><img src="img/map.jpg" alt="google map" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="center">

        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

// This is the script for sending email.


// change the email address below to your own email address.
$mailTo = 'info@rare1.ca';


$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name']);
$mailFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email']);
$message_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']);

$headers  = "From: $name <$mailFrom>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$mailFrom>\n";

$message = $message_text;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers );

?>
```

Comment: You're missing the `method="post"` on your form tag. Since it has been omitted, it defaults to `get`. Since your email script doesn't generate any output, you'll probably want to redirect at the end (`header('Location: /test');` i.e. using the name of the HTML page).

Comment: thanks for the help !! where can I put this method="post"

Comment: See my answer below (note that new messages to you are notified by a numeric message indicator in the top left of the site `:)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php script you are sending the mail, but after that you do nothing!, there is no echo.

Add at the end, after sending the mail:

```
echo "Mail sent";
```

And you'll see that message appears.

**EDIT**:

In order to pass a message to the hompage, you need to put the message in the session and then redirect to the hompage:

```
$_SESSION['myMsg'] = "some message";
header("location: /hompage.php");
```

Now, on the hompage, add somewhere in the script where you want to add the message:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['myMsg'])){
    $message = $_SESSION['myMsg'];
    //do something with message
}
```

It is also a good idea to clean the session when done, you can do it using:

```
session_unset(); // clears all session varaibles

unset($_SESSION['myVar']); // clear specific variable
```

Comment: thank you.would it be possible to have the message stay on the homepage though ?

Comment: sure, by using header("Location: /homepage.php"), but if you want a message to display in that page, you'll also need to put it in the session and then read it in the homepage

Comment: thank you !!! could you please elaborate on homepage.php ? sorry I am quite new to this

Answer (score 3):

When you click submit, you are redirected to `sendemail.php`. That page has no content as you can easily see from the code. That is why the page you land on after hitting submit is blank.

Hopefully, this helped :)

UPDATE:

You could go for something like this:

```
if(mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, $headers )) 
   echo 'Mail successfully sent!';
else
   echo 'Sorry! Something went wrong...';
```

With this your page will have some content and will not look anymore like nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps, however the email i got returned with blank information, is there something wrong with the html aspect as well ?

Comment: @AlanLawlessness - see the comment I've made under your question.

Comment: @halfer thank you !! sorry I missed it as I am quite new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you're using a form with a `get` method, so it will create variables in the query string in your URL. These are accessible with `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Whilst you could switch your `$_POST` references to `$_GET` - it would work - this is not a good idea. The `post` action is suitable for events that should not be repeated by a page refresh, like sending an email or modifying the database. So, the solution is to modify your form.

To do so, modify your form thusly instead:

```
<form action="sendemail.php" class="form" method="post">
```